# How to create new data when exception in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm begginer to develop API in django rest framework. I want to create API for app mobile.

The service has the following functionality:

- Creates a new user if it was not found by mail
- Show all data of the user, if it was found.

**Model:**

```
class Users(models.Model):
    sync_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    points = models.IntegerField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sync_id

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sequence_name = 'SEQ_ID'
        # Query the database for the next sequence value.
        from django.db import connection
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT %s.nextval FROM DUAL;" % (sequence_name))
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        self.sync_id = row[0]
        return super(Users, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'
        unique_together = (('email'),)
```

**view:**

```
def users_detail_email(request, email):
    try:
        users = Users.objects.filter(email=email)
    except Users.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = UsersSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I have already wroten code of API for show all data of user if he was found. But i need help for create it if it was not found

I tryed to add the following code in views, but it's saved nothing

```
 try:
        users = Users.objects.filter(email=email)
    except Users.DoesNotExist:
        context= {"sync_id": 99999999, "points": 0, "phone": "","email": email}
        serializer = UsersSerializer(data=context.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Django has wonderful `User` built in object within `django.contrib.auth`. Why do you not use it and rely on your custom model instead?

Comment: Because a lot of fields from django.contrib.auth are not important for me, for example "first_name", "last_name", "password" and e.t.s.+ groups и user_permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the dictionary to the `UserSerializer`:

```
serializer = UsersSerializer(data=context)
```

I just don't get how it's supposed to work if you call something that doesn't exist. Didn't you got a 500 error with a traceback ?

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
If you do as you do, nothing changes:
try:
        users = Users.objects.filter(email=email)
    except Users.DoesNotExist:
        context= {'sync_id': 99999999, 'points': 0, 'phone': 9343,'email': email}
        serializer = UsersSerializer(context)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

Comment: Maybe start with basics such as do you have an exception during the request ? What's the response ? what's the response status code then

Comment: i got status 200 ok and response is "[]"

Comment: Sure, you don't return any data when it succeeds but it should be in the database or whatever store you're using.

Comment: Ok, but i want to create it using context= {"sync_id": 99999999, "points": 0, "phone": "","email": email} and return new user if i don't found user by mail